# Crystal Reports Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

VB.net program that gets report name, login info and parameters from a command line.  Within the Visual Studio  debug environment it runs without error.  When the program is run directly from a command prompt I get a blank preview screen and an "error 91 Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the third line:

```
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
WriteErrorToLog(666, "got new report doc ")  'this gets logged
cryRpt.Load(sReportName)
WriteErrorToLog(666, "report loaded")  'this does not, error 91 is logged
```

The arguments in the command line run are copied from the same text file into the project's Start Options command line arguments and the actual cmd window.

Any ideas on why it works in the IDE but not on it's own?

TIA,
Phil

Comment: `Error 91`?? That's VB6 not VB.NET

Comment: It appears that error 91 is coming from one of the Crystal dlls

Comment: Figured out why the difference between VS environment on stand-alone:  VS debug inserts the "ProgramName.vshost.exe" as an initial parameter before the parameters specified as command line arguments